# Brightness problem in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, brightness

I own a ACER ASPIRE5734Z that has a Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4500 @ 2.30GHz × 2. I tried this solution,but did not work out:

Open terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T ) and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You will find this line in the new opened window:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update your grub and while rebooting your PC, it will set an extra parameter on the grub menu during boot. This problem might have occur on due to the upgrade on kernel.

Could there be another solution to problem?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

1. `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. find the line starting with

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
   ```
3. add `"acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` to the options, for example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
4. run `sudo update-grub2`
5. reboot